# Invalid Procedure or call argument for DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, invalid-argument

I've searched for a solution to the invalid procedure or call argument that I'm getting for **DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14**.  I only found an answer that relates to running code between different versions of excel.  I'm only running this in 2010, so I'm not sure why this is happening.
Any help is appreciated!
Here is the code.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Dog Report!R1C1:R243C54", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pets!R2C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Comment: Are you sure the sheet "Dog Report" contains data from "A1:BB1" as the field names for the pivot table? The `SourceData:= "Dog Report!R1C1:R243C54"` states that the source data goes from `A1:BB243` in sheet "Dog Report". Btw.: Should be better `SourceData:= "'Dog Report'!R1C1:R243C54"`. Note the sheet name in quotes since it contains a space.

Comment: Also make sure, there is not already a pivot table with `TableName:= "PivotTable1"`.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure the sheet "Dog Report" contains data from `A1:BB1` as the field names for the pivot table The `SourceData:= "Dog Report!R1C1:R243C54"` states that the source data goes from `A1:BB243` in sheet "Dog Report". Btw.: The reference should be better `SourceData:= "'Dog Report'!R1C1:R243C54"`. Note the sheet name in quotes since it contains a space.

Also make sure, there is not already a pivot table with `TableName:= "PivotTable1"` in worksheet "Pets".

To do so you could code:

```
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim bPivotTable1Exists As Boolean

With ActiveWorkbook

 With .Worksheets("Pets")
  For Each pvtTable In .PivotTables
   If pvtTable.Name = "PivotTable1" Then
    bPivotTable1Exists = True
   End If
  Next
 End With

 If Not bPivotTable1Exists Then
  .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'Dog Report'!R1C1:R243C54", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pets!R2C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
 Else
  'do something if pivot table already exists
 End If

End With
```

If it still fails, then make sure, the worksheet "Pets" does not contain data in the range the new pivot table will need. But that would not throw an error but causing a confirm dialog.

Furthermore: The sheet "Pets" must exists and be a worksheet and not a diagram sheet.

If it still fails, the I would do the creation process in two parts. One for pivot cache and another for pivot table. So we can determine what exactly is failing:

```
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim bPivotTable1Exists As Boolean

With ActiveWorkbook

 With .Worksheets("Pets")
  For Each pvtTable In .PivotTables
   If pvtTable.Name = "PivotTable1" Then
    bPivotTable1Exists = True
   End If
  Next
 End With

 If Not bPivotTable1Exists Then
  Set pvtCache = .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'Dog Report'!R1C1:R243C54", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

  With .Worksheets("Pets")
   .Range("A2:C19").ClearContents
  End With

  Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Pets!R2C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
 Else
  'do something if pivot table already exists
 End If

End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Yes I'm sure data from "A1:BB1" Contains the field names for the pivot table, as I have used it for other pivots in other sheets in the same workbook.  Also, I have been careful to make sure that there is not not already a pivot table with TableName:= "PivotTable1"  I've added the quotes as well and unfortunately I'm still getting the invalid procedure or call argument   error message.  Do you have any other suggestions on how I could fix this

Comment: There is another PivotTable1 in another sheet in the workbook that is using the same data range.  Could that be causing this problem?

Comment: No, other worksheets can contain pivot tables with same name. But see my supplement with hints for further debugging.

Comment: Your second suggestion work great!! Thank you so much!!! Would you mind telling me what was failing?  I'm a novice and typically record most of my vba code and when things fail I run it in code break mode and do my best to fix it that way.  I've learned a lot doing that, but this one was above my current skill set.  Thanks!

Comment: The suggestion should simply separate the creation of the pivot cache from the creation of the pivot table to determine which of these processes is failing. If this now works while doing this in one step as done in your code fails, then I also don't know why. Between the two steps my code clears the cell range in worksheet "Pets" which will be needed for the pivot table. But as said if this celll range would not be empty this should not throw an error but showing an confirm dialog.